# Is $P( A \cup B\, |\, C) $ the same as $P(A | C) + P(B | C) $ ( $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive)

Tags: probability

Is $P( A \cup  B \,|\, C)$ the same as $P(A | C) + P(B | C)$ ?
Here $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Hint: it's the same if they are conditionally mutually exclusive; and they are, if they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Remember:
$$
\begin{align*}
P(A\cup B\mid C)&=\frac{P((A\cup B)\cap C)}{P(C)}\\
&=\frac{P((A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C))}{P(C)}\\
&=\frac{P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C)}{P(C)}\\
&=\frac{P(A\cap C)}{P(C)}+\frac{P(B\cap C)}{P(C)}\\
&=P(A\mid C)+P(B\mid C).
\end{align*}
$$
(In the third line, we used the fact that if $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then $(A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)=\varnothing$.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Remember,

- $A\cap B= \emptyset \implies  (A\cap C) \cap ( B\cap C)=\emptyset\quad \forall C$.
- $(A\cup B)\cap C= (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$
- $P\big(A\cup B \big| C\big) = \dfrac{P\big((A\cup B)\cap C\big)}{P(C)}$